# CLI is very slow lately

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, command-line-interface, ionic3

Developing a mobile app with Ionic 3 / AngularJS, my CLI is very (!) slow, lately. When I type a command and press Enter, it takes about 30 - 120 seconds until the command is even started working on. The performance is especially bad, when I run `ionic cordova run android`. This takes up to 10mins which is really frustrating.

I already tried `npm rebuild node-sass`, however, this didn't improve the performance.

I'm using the command line tool Cmder on Windows 10. However, the same issue occurs when I use Git Bash instead.

`Ionic Info` gives me:

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
    Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 2.1.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
    Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.3

System:

    Node       : v6.11.1
    OS         : Windows 10
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 3.10.10
```

Would be happy about any suggestion what this could be about...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can try turning off the `live-reload` feature which can give you a significant performance boost which using the `ionic cli`.

You can disable `live-reload` by issuing the below command,

```
ionic serve --verbose --nolivereload
```

Hope this helps!